# Reported speach and "until"

Tags: grammar, reported-speech

I have the following sentence:

> I'll be reading you a story until it is time to go to bed.

I need to build a reported speech example from the sentence. So, I have something like:

> She said that she would be reading me a story until it is time to go to bed.

But I have doubts about this part of the sentence: "until it is time to". Should I change "is" to "was" here? No? Yes? Why?

Comment: Idiomatically, it's ***very*** unlikely that a native speaker would use continuous ***will be reading*** rather than simple future ***will read*** here, so it's a fairly pointless exercise asking how the "reported speech" version would be phrased.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks for answer!  I have got the exercise from popular exercises book in Russia. The author is "Голицынский Юрий Борисович" the book title is "Английский язык. Грамматика. Сборник упражнений". You can check it, for example, here https://www.ozon.ru/product/angliyskiy-yazyk-grammatika-sbornik-uprazhneniy-141427136/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=RF_Product_Shopping_Books_newclients_super&gclid=Cj0KCQiA34OBBhCcARIsAG32uvN1-fIBnYbbWEdxUBUYgHriECW08Y5xTHOJmcn_p9OS4sZXBKxeMUEaAjVcEALw_wcB

Comment: It may be that the equivalent *Russian* phrasing for your example naturally uses a continuous verb form here. There's no doubt that (non-standard) *Indian* English overuses the continuous (particularly with verbs of *perception*, which is why mainstream Anglophones easily recognise "non-native speaker" when an Indian says anything like *I **am seeing** what you mean* instead of ***I see...***). English really only has ***two*** tenses (Present, and "not-Present"), and we don't often stray too far into "exotic" verb forms.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica thanks! Now I know how to check if an Indian person talk with me or not) So, your comment gives me a reason to ask. Will it correct in this way: "She said that she WILL read me a story" - here I broke the rule. I mean "will" instead of "would". But in the beginning I have "She said" - past. Not "she says". So I broke Sequence of tenses. Is it awful for a native speaker?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica oh, you know! I just recognized I can use your advice in  the sentence from my previous comment! So what is the better: "Now I know how to check if an Indian person talk with me" or "Now I know how to check if an Indian person is talking with me".

Comment: *Now I know how to **tell** if an Indian person **is talking** with me.* Except native Anglophones wouldn't normally phrase it like that in the first place. *Now I will be able to tell if the person talking to me is Indian*, perhaps. Or just *Now I will be able to recognise Indian English* (it's usually better to refer to the category / behaviour, rather than potentially "stigmatising" an actual individual).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you report speech you are describing what happened, so it makes sense to use past tense for all the verbs that relate to past times.  So "until it was time for bed".

> She said that she would be reading me a story until it was time to go to bed.

Sticking strictly to the structure and grammar in the original can make it easier, but there is no need, you can paraphrase reported speech, and this can make the sentence more natural:

> She told me that she would read to me until my bedtime.

Comment: If the speech is being reported before bedtime, it would also be possible to say "She said that she will be reading me a story until it is time for bed."